# jOOQ override type length for a specific dialect

Tags: java, jooq

I would like to create a `DataType` that behaves like `SQLDataType.VARCHAR`, except on sql server it has triple the specified length, is that possible?

The following code should create `varchar(15)` on MySQL, but `varchar(45)` on SQL Server:

```java
create.createTable("table")
      .column("col1", myVarchar.length(15))
      .execute();
```

I think this would work, if the `construct()` method and the big `DefaultDataType` constructor were not package private:

```java
myVarchar = new DefaultDataType<>(null, String.class, "varchar(l)");
new DefaultDataType<>(SQLDialect.MYSQL, myVarchar, "varchar", "char");
new SqlServerCharType(myVarchar);

private class SqlServerCharType extends DefaultDataType<String> {
    public SqlServerCharType(DataType<String> baseType) {
        super(SQLDialect.SQLSERVER, baseType, "varchar", "varchar(max)");
    }

    DefaultDataType<String> construct(Integer newPrecision, Integer newScale, Integer newLength, Nullability newNullability, boolean newReadonly, Generator<?, ?, String> newGeneratedAlwaysAs, QOM.GenerationOption newGenerationOption, QOM.GenerationLocation newGenerationLocation, Collation newCollation, CharacterSet newCharacterSet, boolean newIdentity, Field<String> newDefaultValue) {
        return new DefaultDataType(this, newPrecision, newScale, newLength * 3, newNullability, newReadonly, newGeneratedAlwaysAs, newGenerationOption, newGenerationLocation, newCollation, newCharacterSet, newIdentity, newDefaultValue);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to somehow do this with a `Binding`? Is my only option to wait until I have a connection, know the dialect, and do something like this?

```java
create.createTable("table")
      .column("col1", multiply(create, SQLDataType.VARCHAR(15))
      .execute();
...
private <T> DataType<T> multiply(Scope scope, DataType<T> type) {
    if (scope.dialect().family().equals(SQLDialect.SQLSERVER) && type.isString()) {
        return type.length(type.length() * 3);
    }
    return type;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your last example?

Comment: I can live with it, but if I use it in 50 places it would be easier to have some static setup and then use the `myVarchar`. So I was just wondering if there is some way to do it, which I missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement an [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/) that replaces any [`QOM.CreateTable`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/QOM.CreateTable.html) query by an alternative if your criteria match, e.g.:

```java
ExecuteListener.onRenderStart(ctx -> {
    if (ctx.family() == SQLSERVER
        && ctx.query() instanceof QOM.CreateTable ct
        && ct.$tableElements().stream().anyMatch(e ->
               e instanceof Field<?> f && f.getDataType().isString())
    ) {
        ctx.query(ct.$tableElements(ct.$tableElements()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> e instanceof Field<?> f && f.getDataType().isString()
                ? DSL.field(
                    f.getQualifiedName(),
                    f.getDataType().length(f.getDataType().length() * 3))
                : e
            )
            .toList()
        ));
    }
});
```

This will work anywhere with jOOQ now, including e.g. the parser:

```java
configuration.set(l);
configuration.dsl()
             .parser()
             .parseQuery("create table t (i int, j varchar(10))")
             .execute();
```

As you can then see in the logs:

```
Executing query          : create table t (i int, j varchar(30))
```